# split the string at special character

Tags: regex, python-3.x

I want to print the number followed by '#' character(need to print 32 in that string).

```
    from __future__ import print_function
    import re

    b = '3rd-libraries #32'
    m = re.split(r'[ ](?=#)', b)
    print (m)
```

list output:

```
   ['3rd-libraries', '#32']
```

Comment: Why not `b.split('#')`?

Comment: i'm trying to match the regex. i've tried that thing. Thanks!

Comment: Why are you using `from __future__ import print_function` if you're using Python 3?

Answer (score 0):

To print out the first (!) digits after a hash, you could do:

```
import re

b = '3rd-libraries #32'
m = re.search(r'#(\d+)', b)
print m.group(1)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is works.

```
   from __future__ import print_function
    import re

    b = '3rd-libraries #32'
    m = re.split(r'#', b)
    print (m[1])
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use split when you just need to capture one value. I'd recommend using regex [lookahead](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-lookarounds.html) instead.

```
(?<=#)\d+
```

Example:

```
import re

text = "3rd-libraries #32"

m = re.search(r'(?<=#)\d+', text)
if m:
    print m.group()
```

Output:

```
32
```